# Apigee - How to exclude fields on WSDL call

Tags: apigee

I am using Apigee REST to SOAP to REST Proxy.

After creating the WSDL proxy and deploying it. I see all the parameters that could be sent to the SOAP endpoint. Let call it param1, param2, param3, all optional. But Validation on it is [0-9A-Fa-f]{8}, so that means each param if not empty must be 8 characters long.

The problem I am having is when param2 is null. Some reason the proxy still includes that within the request causing validation error.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I basically wants this. http://xxx.apigee.com/myrestendpoint?param1=xxx&param3=xxx

The soap will not include param2, only sending param1 and param3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the approach of Json to Xml to fix my issue described above. Basically it will generate the XML from a json I pass, and modify my BuildSoap to use the Converted Text.

Example

```
{School : {
  teachers : { teacher: [
    {id:123}, {id:456}
  ]}
}
```

will become

```
<School>
  <teachers>
    <teacher>
      <id>123</id>
    </teacher>
    <teacher>
      <id>456</id>
    </teacher>
  </teachers>
</school>
```

And I add that to my BuildSoap

```
...<soap:envelop><soap:body>{xmlFromJson}</soap:body></soap:envelop>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not done this for params, but I have done it for optional fields in a SOAP message. In my case I am  POSTing a JSON message which will be converted to a SOAP XML message for the backend WSDL. The SOAP message has optional fields which cannot be empty (e.g. ) so in my XSLT that builds the SOAP message, I check to see if the field exists and populate otherwise, don't populate at all.

For example:

`<xsl:if test="/task/comments"><comments_txt><value><xsl:value-of select="/task/comments"/></value></comments_txt></xsl:if>`

Your SOAP message will not be passing the params as params, rather they would be converted to the SOAP XML message. So maybe run an XSLT on that message to strip out empty elements that came from the missing param.

Sorry I don't have a concrete answer, but maybe this will help.

Comment: This was something I was thinking I may have to do, use an XSLT on the Soap Envelop base on a Json. I just need to figure out how Apigee wire these things together. I was hoping there is something that Apigee has in their tools that does this automatically, but from the answers it seems like there isn't a feature like that.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your request with an AssignMessage policy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AssignMessage async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Assign-Message">
    <DisplayName>Assign Message</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <Remove>
        <QueryParams/>      
    </Remove>
    <Add>
        <QueryParams>
          <QueryParam name="param1">{request.queryparam.param1}</QueryParam>
          <QueryParam name="param3">{request.queryparam.param3}</QueryParam>
        </QueryParams>
    </Add>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <AssignTo createNew="false" transport="http" type="request"/>
</AssignMessage>
```

The Remove block will strip out all query parameters and then the Add will allow you to put back in just the ones you want.

Comment: That is the thing. I want to remove query param that is null at runtime. So in my example, param2 is null, but someone can be passing in param1,2,3. and someone can pass in param1. So I need something that will remove null parameters.

Comment: So you need to rewrite param3 to param2?

Comment: No. I need to remove the param all together. with above logic you have, remove all queryParmas, Then for all request.queryparam, if not null, <queryParam name="..."> otherwise don't even mention that param.

Comment: I think I might need to do an XSLT base on the request.queryparam, but I am hoping that I don't.

Comment: Okay, so it's not that the value of param2=[NULL], it's that the user never passes it through. But you're hardcoding validation on param2.  Correct?

Comment: What I am saying is, I have 3 params that are optional. If they are filled in, they will be validated on the SOAP end. So my scenario is like this. me (passing param1, param3) -> REST -> Apigee (sees params2 is null, so only generate <queryParam name="param1"><queryParam name="param3">) -> SOAP -> final endpoint (Validate param1, param3, skip validation on param2 because it is not passed or null)

Comment: Can you rewrite Param3 to param2 if  param2 doesn't exist? I'm leaning towards a javascript rewrite of the queryparams...

Comment: No, because the validation behind param2 and 3 are different. param1,2,3 are different data type.

Comment: Okay... so maybe we need to work on your example: is your request actually resource?pararm1=xxx&param2=&param3=xxx?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking.